# json config files not auto formatted

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, prettier

In vscode, some config files does not auto format with prettier.

For instancce, this file : 
C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets\php.json

The file is valid json, but on save, prettier does not format the file. Why ?

Formatting works on other files, like "settings.json", "package.json", "composer.json", ...

Curiously, if I drag and drop the file in vscode, then auto-format works.

Comment: What language mode are you in when it does not work? (Bottom right next to line numbers, spaces etc.) I suspect you may not be in JSON mode, but when you are dragging and dropping it may perhaps autodetect. If you click it you have more options.

Comment: It is also in JSON mode, with prettier and formatting activated.

Answer (score 2):

In Vscode, you can use "Format Document (forced)"
steps to do this:-
1.open your file.
2.open command palette (ctrl+shift+p).
3.then in search bar search for "Format Document (Forced)" , then select this and it will automatically format your file.

Comment: What exactly does this "Format Document" do?
I have a .json file which I read in, edit, & save (using python).  The orig doc shows up already formatted, but the saved doc shows up not formatted (i.e. single long line).  Knowing what "Format Document" does might help me correct the issue I'm having.